# Java static reference vs dynamic reference and calls

Tags: java, static, public

Here I will post two simplified versions of my code (but it is self sufficient, you don't need to know what are other variables and so on).

I need the class including my problem to import my class Synchronous_Writing from another package. I need this class to be static as various classes must call it and modify the object created at first subsequently,
and it is not really an option to pass the data from one class to another as that would make the code really unreadable...

This class is public, but still access from the current class involve some problem described below the version below.
Thanks by advance for your help.

Backbone of Synchronous_Writing:

```
public final Synchronous_Writing {

     public Synchronous_Writing() {
     // variable to initialize
     }
     public static void writer ()
     {
     //operation to be performed
     }
 }
```

1st version:

```
import Synchronous_Writing;

public classFileToEdit_Parser {
  // A public static final class
  Synchronous_Writing SyncedWriter ; // note to an editor; this is a ";", not a {

  public FileToEdit_Parser  (
    String inputFile_FileToEdit, 
    String outputFile_EditedFile, 
    Charset charset, 
    String HitList_fieldsSeparator, 
    String CommentLine) 
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
  {
      SyncedWriter = new Synchronous_Writing(
      outputFile_EditedFile, charset, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
  }

  protected void parser_writer(Path FileToEdit) 
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException 
  {
    SyncedWriter.writer();
  }
}
```

//The problem here is that the compiler says that "the static method writer(String) from the type Synchronous_Writing should be accessed in a static way" (logical since Synchronous_Writing is static)

2nd version:

```
import Synchronous_Writing;
// A public static final class
public classFileToEdit_Parser
{
  public FileToEdit_Parser (
    String inputFile_FileToEdit, 
    String outputFile_EditedFile, 
    Charset charset, 
    String HitList_fieldsSeparator, 
    String CommentLine) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
  {
    SyncedWriter = new Synchronous_Writing(
      outputFile_EditedFile, charset, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
  }

  protected void parser_writer(Path FileToEdit) 
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException 
  {
  // SyncedWriter.writer () 
  // won't work, I don't really understand why since 
  // the constructor is public, but I still can't access it

  Synchronous_Writing.writer () 
  // will work, but the compiler keeps saying that SyncedWriter
  // variable is not used (which is quite true, since only the
  // constructor is initialized)
  }
}
```

To correct 1st version's problem, I thus suppressed Synchronous_Writing SyncedWriter; in class declaration and switched to a variable call through the class and not the object. Suppressing Synchronous_Writing SyncedWriter; was not mandatory, still, but it doesn't change the problem.

My second problem is that SyncedWriter.writer () won't work, I don't really understand why since the constructor is public, but I still can't access it.
Synchronous_Writing.writer ()   will work, but the compiler keeps saying that SyncedWriter variable is not used (which is quite true, since only the constructor is initialized)

In the end, both codes are botched in some way, and I would like to know it properly, so please feel free to give your insights.

Comment: You know what will help you to avoid these confusions? Following java's coding conventions. Mainly - a variable name should start with a lower case letter, and not upper case. First letter as upper case is "reserved" to class names. (which yours - start with lower case)\

Comment: How is is the actual `SyncedWriter.writer()` method defined? Also, really, please have some naming, indentation, and case consistency, because even this small piece of code is really confusing as it is.

Comment: There is no static top-level class in java. You should read about language and java conventions a bit.

Comment: Thanks to editors for indentation (and sorry if it was really unreadable for you), I think SO posting system messed up with what was done automatically by Eclipse. Sorry for user3360241, I meant "final", static is for writer method, I will edit.

Comment: Also, no need to get as angry as that, everybody starts as a beginner some day. Maybe it is evident to you, for me it can happen I confuse things. It's not a lack of reading or discipline, it's a lack of habit.

Answer (score 1):

`static` in java means, that a method do not know about any context except passed parameters and other static variables.

You are trying to create a context in `Synchronous_Writing` and than call a static method on this context.
Calling the method without the step to initialize the context in `Synchronous_Writing` will probably case an exception.
This is a bad practice and not self-explanatory code.

If you need a static method, make sure it doesn't depend on any context which needs to be initialized.

Comment: Just to be sure to understand, by "creating a context", do you refer to object SyncedWriter initialization in the first version or to the line SyncedWriter = new Synchronous_Writing(...) in the constructor? actually I use the constructor to initialize and assign variables with values specific to the class calling it, but the method needs to be static because the processes it performs need both this "context" created in the constructor and the "historical data" from past operation.

Comment: It may seem like bad practice to you, but it actually make the code a lot simpler, readable and maintainable at my current level (and I need the program now, not in two years, so as long it is for my own use I will deal with the shame of bad coding), cause I can't use fancy techniques for that, I only know simple constructs and few basic classes. I plan to improve and make it better, but so far I could not find a logic/algorithm easier to implement that what I did with this constructor. I just want to know if simple change can be done to avoid the catch22 situation

Comment: which is   "static reference done properly but don't work for unknown reason", "dynamic reference done badly but which works". I wondered if it was a question of scope but it is not, since everything I need is declared at class level.

Comment: @AndoJurai **1)** Can you post Exceptions you got? **2)** From what I see, you do some initialization on the `FileToEdit_Parser`, than probably use this object somewhere, where the method `parser_writer` is called? In the 2nd version there is no reference to the object in the class  `FileToEdit_Parser`, so there is no way to call `SyncedWriter.writer ()` (I assume SyncedWriter is Object like in the 1st example and not Class). Your first attempt is pretty OK! And there is no need for the `writer` to be declared static! You have encapsulated a `Synchronous_Writing` object...

Comment: ... and you grant access to it in the `FileToEdit_Parser#parser_writer ` method. Thats pretty Ok (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Did you tried to make the `writer` method not static?

Comment: I had no exception. Just Eclipse keeping on telling that 1st version is improper because I create the object (to inject variable values proper to this class into it, so that its writer method work with both these and the accumulated data from before which is stored from its static nature), and call the method through it, while I should call it in a static way. But if I did that, then it would keep telling me that object is not used. (You're right for 2nd version, I figured that too).

Comment: I think if I want the method not to be static, I have to make variables from its class or constructor static. But then that means that the code inside the method become a lot less self explanatory since you have to go check for these variables instead of knowing that only the values passed to the method will change its state and no other... But maybe is it a better way of doing things?

Comment: @AndoJurai I have no idea how you implemented the method so that "the code become a lot less self explanatory" in the case when the method is not static. Paste it to e.x. pastebin so I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for offering further help but there I can't, since it's something for work. I guess I can do with this for now.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you want to modify an instance (object) of a class from multiple other classes, use the `Singleton` design pattern. You only need to have a static getter and all your problems will be solved. Google `Singleton design pattern java example` and be convinced of it's awesomeness and applicability!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this constructive answer. By doing the things basically, I was stuck between two bad solutions. I think it will help.